# How can I remove the PowerShell start text?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

PowerShell starting at version 6 has a Unix-style `/etc/issue` that mentions a link to the documentation.

```
PowerShell v6.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/pscore6-docs
Type 'help' to get help.
```

This is fine, but:

- I know where the documentation is
- I know I launched PowerShell 6

How can I remove some or all of the message? If I remember correctly, PowerShell 5 still had the copyright message, so maybe I can't remove that, but getting rid of the last three lines would still help.

Comment: This question became even more relevant after MS decided to start advertising every new minor release in the startup banner.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If you are using the new Windows Terminal then:

1. Go to Settings:

   [image: Windows Terminal Settings]
2. Add the argument `-nologo` to the PowerShell command line:

   [image: Powershell Command Line]

Comment: As an additional tip to **VS Code** users, you can add the `-nologo` argument to the integrated terminal by setting `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": "-nologo",` in the `settings.json`.

Comment: Agreed re VS Code, altho I sugest making it `["-NoLogo"]`, since technically that field takes an array.

Comment: You may need to add the "commandLine" option yourself. In my settings, it wasn't there.

Answer (score 78):

Pass the [`-nologo` option](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff629472.aspx).

> **-NoLogo** Starts the PowerShell console without displaying the copyright banner.

```
pwsh.exe -nologo ...other arguments...
```

Comment: Just at tip: If you're using the new Windows Terminal (highly recommended) then you can edit it's settings to have it launch powershell.exe -nologo too, which works great

Answer (score 18):

From @sandu's answer, it could be improved as below.

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
   "PowerShell": {
       "source": "PowerShell",
       "args": ["-noLogo"]
   }
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell",
```

Answer (score 14):

Now you can add `-nologo` in Windows Terminal settings:

[image]

Comment: How do you get to the Windows Terminal settings?

Comment: @Stevoisiak Go to Microsoft Store and search for "Windows Terminal" and then install it.

Comment: @Stevoisiak Click on the down-arrow in the title bar area.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way would be to add `Clear-Host` to the top of your `$profile` file.

Comment: Upvoting, since this is helopful, but going to hold out to see if there's a file or registry entry I can edit to actually remove the text rather than just clear it.

Comment: This can lead to undesired behavior when calling powershell from other shell.

Answer (score 4):

You can open powershell and input `$profile`, you will get `Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` file's path.
open this file (create one without) by notepad and input a `clear` or `cls` command.Save and exit.
the command of this file will be executed when you open powershell

[image]

Comment: that means switching between terminals randomly clears your screen, not ideal.

Answer (score 3):

As `np8` said under [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63695674/8602926), the way to hide the initial text in the **Visual Studio Code integrated terminal** is as follows:

---

1. Open the workspace settings file (`./.vscode/settings.json`) or the user settings file (search for `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)` in the command palette, opened with <kbd>F1</kbd>)
2. Add the following inside the outer-most "layer" of curly brackets:

   ```json
   "terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": [
       "-nologo"
   ]
   ```

Comment: A fine answer, upvoted, but I removed the text about other shells as this is a powershell question.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was to go to `File > Preferences > Settings` and type `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows` in the search bar (*you can change `windows` with other supported OS if you need to*). There should now be only one option to choose from (*that's why I included `windows`*). Click on the `Edit in settings.json` link bellow it. It should now open `settings.json` and generate the line necessary to modify the default terminal profile. Which looks something like:

```json
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "",
```

Above that line you can create your own profile:

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell -nologo": {
      "source": "PowerShell",
      "args": ["-nologo"]
    }
},
```

Name the profile however you want and add whatever parameters you want. Once you're done. Set the profile name into the option that was previously generated for you. In this example it should look like:

```json
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell -nologo",
```

Save and close. Now when you open a terminal it should have no logo for example.

Comment: The other answers are `deprecated`.
@sandu 's answer can be improved by removing the `-nologo` in the profile name, because the `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows"` only accepts the Valid values: `"PowerShell"`, `"Command Prompt"`, `"Git Bash"`, `"kali-linux (WSL)"`, `"Legacy (WSL)"`.
so the answer could be overwritten like my answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68048772/7333583).

Answer (score 3):

I was fix problem on the top by

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Users of Chinese version can also add -nologo in Windows terminal settings:

As shown in the figure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of doing it :

1. Creating a shortcut with value

> "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -nologo -NoExit -Command "Set-Location c:\Users\%username%"

2. If you are using Windows terminal then you can replace the **source** with

> "commandline": "pwsh.exe -NoLogo"

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the new Windows Terminal in Windows 11,

Go to Settings:

[image: Windows Terminal Settings]

Select the Windows Powershell profile from the left sidebar

[image: Windows Powershell profile in left sidebar]

Add the argument -nologo to the command line:

[image: Powershell Command Line]

Save and be sure to restart your terminal to see the changes.

Comment: This world be better as an update to the existing answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using windows just create a profile and put the command **clear** inside it. 
In PowerShell I'm going to open the profile with notepad:

```
notepad $Profile
```

Answer (score 0):

**Highly Recommended to Use**

Powershell Preview: https://github.com/PowerShell/powershell/releases

**Editing Context Menu**

If you are using Powershell Preview, you can change context menu using `regedit`:

1. Open `regedit`
2. Go to `Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\PowerShell7-previewx64`
3. add flag `-nologo` to `Icon`

[image]

**2. Editing Start Menu Shortcut**

1. In File Explorer go to
   `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
2. Create a shortcut with value
   `"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7-preview\pwsh.exe" -nologo -NoExit -Command "Set-Location c:\\Users\\%username%"`