# How to remove powershell ads and update checks in the Windows Terminal?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-core, windows-terminal

When I start the Windows Terminal, I get the following:

[image]

How do I get rid of the copyright & version notifications, the help URL and the update check?  I just want to get to the command line.

My powershell profile in the settings.json (the config file for the Windows Terminal) is like this:

```
{
    "guid": "{574e775e-4f2a-5b96-ac1e-a2962a402336}",
    "hidden": false,
    "name": "PowerShell",
    "source": "Windows.Terminal.PowershellCore",
    "fontFace": "Cascadia Code PL",
    "startingDirectory": "C:\\Users\\user1\\desktop\\"
}
```

I've seen flags like -nologo and so forth, but I don't have a command line to pass it to.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to I remove the Powershell start text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262269/how-to-i-remove-the-powershell-start-text)

Comment: @user19702, the linked post only addresses _half_ of this question; additionally, this question is specifically focused on Windows Terminal.

Comment: It actually addresses the entire thing. Passing the `-nologo` command starts the environment showing just the command line. And answers there cover Windows Terminal, too.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Update:

- The **answer below** shows you to ***directly edit* your `settings.json` file**.
- As of at least Windows Terminal 1.16, you can **alternatively use the GUI**:<sup>Thanks, [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/196852/chris)</sup>

  - Open the Settings tab (e.g. via <kbd>Ctrl-,</kbd>)
  - At the bottom of the sidebar on the left, click `+ Add a new profile`, and, next to `Duplicate a profile`, select your existing PowerShell (Core) profile, then press the `Duplicate` button.
  - Click on `Command line`, and modify the existing command line by appending `-nologo`, as also shown below.

---

Create a ***custom* [profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-settings) in Windows Terminal's `settings.json` file** as follows (inside the `profiles.list` array property):

As of at least PowerShell 7.2.1 `-nologo` also deactivates update notifications:<sup>Thanks, [Maximilian Hils](https://stackoverflow.com/users/934719/maximilian-hils).</sup>

```
{
    // no strict need for a GUID; create a *new* one, if needed.
    "hidden": false,
    "name": "PowerShell - no logo, no update notification",
    "commandline": "pwsh.exe -nologo"
    // ... other properties omitted.
},
```

In earlier versions you *may* need environment variable `POWERSHELL_UPDATECHECK` to disable update notifications:

```
{
    // no strict need for a GUID; create a *new* one, if needed.
    "hidden": false,
    "name": "PowerShell - no logo, no update notification",
    "commandline": "cmd /c set POWERSHELL_UPDATECHECK=Off & pwsh.exe -nologo"
    // ... other properties omitted.
},
```

- Copy the `startingDirectory` and `fontFace` properties from the *dynamic* profile shown in your question, if desired. ([Dynamic profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/dynamic-profiles) are auto-generated by Windows Terminal itself, depending on what shells are found to be installed; they have a `source` property whose value starts with `Windows.Terminal`, as in the entry shown in your question.
- There is no strict need for a `guid` property in this case (generally, names and GUIDs can be used interchangeably to identify a profile); if you do use one, create a *new* GUID (e.g. with [`New-Guid`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/new-guid)).

  - If you want to use the same `name` value as that of the dynamic PowerShell Core profile, it's best to *hide* the latter by setting its `hidden` property to `true`.
- Custom profiles use a `commandline` property to define what command to execute when a tab with this profile is generated. The value above  assumes that PowerShell's executable, `pwsh.exe`, is in your path; if it isn't and you therefore need to specify a full path, be sure to either *double* `\` chars. (e.g. `\"C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe\"`) or use `/` instead (e.g. `\"C:/Program Files/PowerShell/7/pwsh.exe\"`)
- *May* be required in PowerShell versions before 7.2.1:

  - `cmd /c set POWERSHELL_UPDATECHECK=Off` defines the relevant environment variable to turn off PowerShell's update notifications, and then launches PowerShell.

    - This means that your PowerShell instances will have a `cmd.exe` parent process, but that shouldn't be a problem.
  - You can alternatively define this environment variable *persistently*, via the registry, in which case `cmd.exe` is no longer needed.
- Passing `-nologo` to [PowerShell's CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pwsh) suppresses the "logo", i.e. the copyright message and help hint.

  - As of at least PowerShell 7.2.1, `-nologo` automatically deactivates the update notifications as well - potentially, it has always worked this way.

Comment: That worked out perfectly.  POWERSHELL_UPDATECHECK is now an environment variable.  So the `commandline` is now just `pwsh.exe -nologo`.

Comment: As an extension, if you want to hide the logo in a VScode terminal, you can specify            `"args": ["-nologo"]` in the `"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {"PowerShell": { ... }}` section of your settings json.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't call this a fix, but in case anybody doesn't want to get into the details of disabling terminal settings, you could just ad `clear-host` at the end of your code in your profile file, i have mine right at the bottom and it clears the console every time i open it.