# Unwanted output in the terminal of VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I love visual studio code . But the main problem is when i run a program, i get some unwanted output in the terminal

I attached an image, where the unwanted output is wrapped in red line.Is there any way to get rid of this unwanted output in the terminal ?
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to I remove the Powershell start text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262269/how-to-i-remove-the-powershell-start-text)

Comment: @crashmstr, I do not know how to Pass the -nologo option. Can you please help?

Comment: You need to edit the VS Code JSON settings. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68048772/1441) on that question has what settings to use. I'm not sure why you care about this as it seems inconsequential. You could also open up a separate console window and use a command to clear the screen before running your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked for me:

- Open Visual Studio Code and press <kbd>F1</kbd> to open the **command panel**
- Search for **Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)** and open it. It will open a **settings.json** file
- You may see something like this

```json
{
    "editor.fontSize": 17,
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell"
}
```

- Paste the code below, above
  `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell"`

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": 
{
    "PowerShell": 
    {
        "source": "PowerShell",
        "args": ["-noLogo"]
    }
},
```

- After this, the **settings.json** should be something like this

```json
{
    "editor.fontSize": 17,
    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": 
    {
        "PowerShell": 
        {
            "source": "PowerShell",
            "args": ["-noLogo"]
        }
    },
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "PowerShell"
}
```

- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save and close **settings.json**

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. Install code runner extension
2. Go to Code Runner extensions settings

Search for Executor Map and then click Edit in settings.json
Depending on the programing language that you use add the following instead of default one:

"c": "cls && function prompt{">>"} && $Host.ui.rawui.foregroundcolor = "cyan"  && cd $dir && g++  $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt && echo `n && $Host.ui.rawui.foregroundcolor = "red"",

In case you use C++ then just change "c": to "cpp": and
be aware to to replace gcc to g++ or to clang++ in case you use clang

you can check my videos for detailed explanation

quick:
https://youtu.be/yq8j3AsEOL0

Detailed:
https://youtu.be/WM5iW8SyGpk