# How to get result on VScode similar to Sublime?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use sublime to study python and when i run it gives a clear result.

Then I try shifting to VScode (cause open source and sublime free is abit annoying) and when i run a simple print("Hello World") to test out the result in terminal it shows the following. Every code i run has this and i have to sift through the info to check my output.

```
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\XX\Desktop\python_work\VS_code>  & 'C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'c:\Users\XX\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.8.0\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '57997' '--' 'c:\Users\XX\Desktop\python_work\VS_code\.vscode\Test.py'
Hello World
PS C:\Users\XX\Desktop\python_work\VS_code>
```

Comment: it runs in a terminal, and you get this stuff in a terminal

Comment: customize your terminal prompt to use color, then it differs from the python output

Answer (score 0):

You are using PowerShell as the default shell for your VSCode terminal.

If you want to configure PowerShell to remove the redundant welcome message, check the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262269/how-to-i-remove-the-powershell-start-text).

Alternatively, if you want to switch to another shell, either choose from the available ones with `> Terminal: Select Default Profile` command (Ctrl + Shift + P for Windows/Linux, Cmd + Shift + P for Mac) or add a new one by following the instructions in the [VSCode documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-profiles).

Comment: I honestly am confused and lost. I tried a few of those but cant seem to work it out. Will check on it again or might be something I am doing wrong. For now will continue using sublime. Thanks for the info!