# How do i remove the unnecessary text in the terminal in vscode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, terminal

Hi i'm new into vscode and when i run a program there is some text that i want to get rid of.

[image]

i mainly want to remove the first two paragraphs, but also removing the path would be ideal

i tried code runner but thats not the solution i'm looking for
i also tried changing the color to black but i reckon there is a way to remove it

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262269/how-to-i-remove-the-powershell-start-text) what you're referring to?

Comment: starting the python script is how VSC works and will not be changed, the text has a purpose

Comment: Where does Code Runner not meet your requirements? It can already help you get clean output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the "-NoLogo" start parameter will remove the paragraph of text; If you open your settings file (Ctrl+Shift+P and then type "Settings" -> User Settings JSON), you can use the following bit of configuration:

```
// should go in the main JSON object with the other keys
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    // it might generate some more profiles automatically, but powershell is what matters
    "PowerShell": {
        "source": "PowerShell",
        "icon": "terminal-powershell",
        "args": ["-NoLogo"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe by default those lines will always appear because those are the one that show up when you open cmd on Windows.

Also, by default, the path open to the current project folder, that the reason why you see the path.

You can do a `cls` to clear the terminal, but the path will remain unless you change the directory.

You can read more about VS Code integrated terminal [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/basics) and about terminal profiles [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles)

Answer (score 0):

First go to terminal settings and then the add `-nologo` arg

[image]